# Ubuntu OpenCV Error While reading the rtsp

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp

System information (version)

OpenCV = 4.4.0

Operating System / Platform = Ubuntu

Compiler = Python 3.6.9

Getting Encoding error while Reading a video stream using RTSP as shown below. Initially the reading process starts and while running it shows this errors

```
[hevc @ 0x83b9940] Could not find ref with POC 0

[rtsp @ 0x8325a00] RTP: PT=60: bad cseq ced0 expected=c18a

[rtsp @ 0x8325a00] RTP: PT=60: bad cseq de79 expected=d168

[hevc @ 0x83aefc0] The cu_qp_delta 64 is outside the valid range [-26, 25].

[hevc @ 0x83b9940] Could not find ref with POC 8

[hevc @ 0x83aefc0] CABAC_MAX_BIN : 7

[hevc @ 0x83aefc0] The cu_qp_delta 1094995529 is outside the valid range [-26, 25].

[hevc @ 0x83a05c0] The cu_qp_delta -59 is outside the valid range [-26, 25].

[hevc @ 0x833aa00] The cu_qp_delta 35 is outside the valid range [-26, 25].
```

The code is as shown below

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://********@192.168.0.46:33/Streaming/Channels/101",cv2.CAP_FFMPEG) 
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS,3)
if (cap.isOpened()== False):  
    print("Error Opening the file")
previous_face = None
# Read until video is completed 
while(cap.isOpened()):  # Capture frame-by-frame 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if(np.shape(frame) != ()):
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (780, 540), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        cv2.imshow('video', frame)
```

We tried using nohup in to run this continuously. The code starts running successfully and it reads the stream properly but after a short period of time (Not with in a specific interval of time) the error is been throws and the and stops running.

Comment: Optimized formatting of code